# Additional information in jqgrid grouping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In the following [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/johnnash03/stn2yfxn/), I need meta-info about each grouped data on top.So, let's say if I want sum then sum of each row of individual column (only summable quantity) must appear on top of the grouped column.[grouped sum for tax of one column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaX05.png).

Following is the complete code.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#grid1").jqGrid({
        colModel: [
            { name: "name", label: "Client", width: 53 },
            { name: "invdate", label: "Date", width: 75, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
             formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" } },
            { name: "tax", label: "Tax", width: 41, template: "number" },
            { name: "closed", label: "Closed", width: 59, template: "booleanCheckboxFa", firstsortorder: "desc" },
            { name: "ship_via", label: "Shipped via", width: 87, align: "center", formatter: "select",
             formatoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;DH:DHL", defaultValue: "DH" } }
        ],
        data: [
            { id: "10",  invdate: "2015-10-01", name: "test",   amount: "" },
            { id: "20",  invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test1",  tax: "29.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" },
            { id: "30",  invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test1",  tax: "32.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" },
            { id: "40",  invdate: "2015-10-04", name: "test4",  tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN" },
            { id: "50",  invdate: "2015-10-31", name: "test1",  tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" },
            { id: "60",  invdate: "2015-09-06", name: "test4",  tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" },
            { id: "70",  invdate: "2015-10-04", name: "test4",  tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN" },
            { id: "80",  invdate: "2015-10-03", name: "test8",  tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" },
            { id: "90",  invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test3",  tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN" },
            { id: "100", invdate: "2015-09-08", name: "test1", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN" },
            { id: "110", invdate: "2015-09-08", name: "test11", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" },
            { id: "120", invdate: "2015-09-10", name: "test12", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE" }
        ],
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rownumbers: true,
        pager: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: "invdate",
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "The grid, which uses predefined formatters and templates"
    });
    $("#grid1").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy','name');
});
```

Comment: @Oleg I have upvoted the answers but they will only reflect when I have a reputation of at least 15.

Comment: @Oleg Accepted the previous answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to implement the requirement is the usage of `groupSummaryPos: ["header"]` property of `groupingView` and to define `summaryType: "sum"` and optionally `summaryTpl` in the columns, where you want to display summary information (the column `amount` in your case)

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/stn2yfxn/9/ which displays the result like below

[image]

Comment: How to display the sum of tax and total even if the data is grouped by amount?

Comment: @johndoe: You need just define `summaryType: "sum"` in the columns where you want to see the total in the group (`tax` and `total` in your case).